# PHP Array into array

Tags: php, arrays

I've had a look through searches but there are so many differently worded question that I'm not sure which I should be looking for. Nor can I think how to word this to the best of my ability, but here goes:

I would like to take a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` result and create an array for each row.

Let's say the result had two rows:

```
[0][0] = Cheese
[0][1] = 1
[1][0] = Milk
[1][1] = 2
```

How can I drop those into a newly created array let's say called `$items`?

What I'm hoping to achieve is:

```
$items = array(
    array("Cheese",1),
    array("Milk", 2)
);
```

The only code I have so far is this:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {
        $items[$i][] = $row[$i];
    }
}
```

I have not tried this, but I have this very unsettling feeling that it definitely won't be working.

Comment: You'll never know until you try. Then have a look at `array_push()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Try it, then explain why it didn't work (if it didn't). No point asking us when you can try it yourself...

Comment: "*I have not tried this, but I have this very unsettling feeling that it definitely won't be working.*" Why not try it and see what errors you get specifically, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this not do it?

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    foreach($row as $r) {
       $items[] = $r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, and was in the process of adding a couple of rows to test if this worked so I could come back with some results. Sorry guys, should have tested before popping the question! >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) 
{
   foreach($row as $value){
      $new_arr[][$value[0]] = $value[1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) 
{
   $arr = [];
   foreach ($row as  $value) 
      $arr[] = $value;
   $items[] = $arr;
}
var_dump($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_result::fetch_all()
```

"Returns an array of associative or numeric arrays holding result rows"

I think you're thinking too hard. A two dimensional array is already an array containing arrays. In your case, the result of fetch_all is precisely an array containing 'an array for each row'

If you're not intending to store the whole result set then you can do:

```
$rows[] = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row() && $someCondition) $rows[] = $row;
```

but really you'd be better off to put a LIMIT on the query if possible.